# C++: value_type versus make_pair, which is faster for map insert?

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

```
typedef map<KeyType, ValType> KVMap;
KVMap kvmap;

kvmap.insert( KVMap::value_type( key, val ) );
kvmap.insert( make_pair( key, val ) );
```

Which of the above options to insert to a STL map is always faster? Why?

Note: I am well aware that `insert()` is faster than using `[]=` for adding (not updating) key-value pairs to a map. Please assume that my query is about adding, not updating. Hence I have restricted it to `insert()`.

Comment: Unless your program consists solely of inserts to maps, do you really think any speed difference will be noticeable? You should get a profile to profile your finished, clean, maintainable program to see what the slow spots actually are. And there shouldn't be a difference, after inlining.

Comment: GMan: The difference was tiny. See my comment to Karl's answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Chances are that the first will be *'epsilon-faster'*, because of this (from 23.3.1 in the standard) :

```
typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type;

[...]

pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& x);
```

- In the first version, you directly construct the appropriate type expected by `std::map<K,V>::insert`
- In the second version, a conversion using `std::pair` template constructor is involved. Indeed, `std::make_pair` will most likely deduce its template arguments to `KeyType` and `ValType`, thus returning a `std::pair<KeyType, ValType>`.

  This does not match the parameter type of `std::map<K,V>::insert`, which is `std::pair<const KeyType, ValType>` (the difference being the `const`-qualified first). The `std::pair` conversion constructor will be used to create a `std::pair<const K, V>` from the `std::pair<K, V>`.

To be fair, I don't believe you could even measure the difference (and I'm not even sure that popular compilers will actually generate a different code for these).

Comment: It's not inlining *per se* that would eliminate the overhead, but rather the subsequent elision of copy construction/assignment etc.

Comment: icecrime: make_pair involves conversions, how does this make it epsilon-faster?

Comment: @Ashwin of course that what a mistake in the first sentence :) Fixed

Answer (score 12):

There actually is an argument to be made for `value_type` over `make_pair`. This is because, for various arcane reasons, `make_pair` accepts its arguments by value. On the other hand, `value_type`, an alias for `std::pair<const Key, value>`, will have its constructor called with the arguments passed by const reference.  There's a potential loss of efficiency from the pass-by-value in `make_pair` versus pass-by-reference, which could in theory have a noticeable impact on your program.

Another issue to be worried about with `make_pair` is that `make_pair` will usually create a pair of type `std::pair<Key, Value>` versus the `std::pair<const Key, Value>` needed inside the `map`.  This means that there might be another unnecessary copy being made, this time of the `pair` to get the conversion working correctly.

In short, using `make_pair` might cause two completely unnecessary copies of the key and value to get made, while using the `value_type` constructor has none.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a supplementation.

`insert( make_pair(...) )`
calls copy constructor 4 times notionally because of the reason other
answerers mentioned.

`insert( value_type(...) )`
calls copy constructor 2 times.

`operator[]`
calls default constructor once and copy constructor 2 times
in a typical implementation.
default constructor is called inside `operator[]` for
`insert( value_type( ..., mapped_type() ) )`.
copy constructor is called once for copying `insert()`'s argument(`pair`),
and once to copy-construct an internal node of the map.

So, if you use `insert` with `make_pair`, 
it cannot be said that `insert` is always faster than `operator[]` even for adding.
Probably, it depends on the situation.
As you may know, in view of the above, `emplace` was proposed for the new
standard.

Answer (score 2):

They are fundamentally the same thing. `KVMap::value_type` is a typedef for `std::pair<KeyType, ValType>`, so that's just calling the constructor. `std::make_pair` is a template function that simply calls the constructor (it exists because template types can be deduced for free functions, but not for constructors). Once all the unbelievably-standard optimizations are done, there is no reason for there to be any difference.

I don't know how you're testing, but there are many, many ways to do that wrong.

As for `insert()` vs. assigning via `operator[]`, the latter has to do more work conceptually (when you add a new element this way, it first is supposed to default-construct an element, and then assign over top of it), but depending on the `ValType`, it could conceivably be optimized into basically the same thing again.

Comment: @icecrime I think you do have a point. C++ is kind of wonky imo when it comes to deducing const-ness. :)

Comment: They are the same assuming key, value have the correct types. Its usually not going to be a problem but sometimes the auto conversions may be unexpected hence I prefer using value_type(key, val). Example: Key="std::string". make_pair("Plop", 1) does not initially make a value_type object though it will get converted eventually and optimizations may remove all the conversions on a good compiler.

Comment: Karl: You are right about the testing. One seems to be a tiny bit faster for insertion of 10^3 elements and the other for 10^5 elements. I am suspecting it might be due to factors external to this.